# [Python][Keras] softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to run the following code in order to create a Convolutional Neural Network. The code is from a tutorial I found.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

I've already searched for answers but nothing worked. Some people said to downgrade Keras, others to upgrade it with "pip install -U keras tensorflow", but I still get the same error message.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a problem with the version of of tensorflow and Keras you are using. My assumption is that you first installed tensorflow and then later installed keras. Softmax is relatively new (probably earlier this year). Your version of tensorflow is probably from before Softmax is added, but the version of Keras is from after it was added. Therefore when you call Softmax, keras tries to call it in tensorflow but it receives an error.

**What You Need to Do**
You should update *both* Keras and Tensorflow to the current version and double check the version. If you are using a package manager such as Anaconda it is possible that even after you updated Keras and Tensorflow you were using an older version. Therefore double check that you are using the the current version

Comment: It seems to be working ! Thank you very much for your help :)